# Do something if two exceptions in a row occur in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, try-except

I am writing a python script that changes to multiple directories and parses different files from within those (eventually I am populating a MySQL database with the parsed data). Actually I first try to change to a `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` and parse the tables I want. If `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` does not exist, I try to change to `/baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same` and parse the same tables that I can parse from `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same`.

In my code, which is already quite too long to paste in here, I have a `try except` statement that, thus far, prints a message in case a dir (i.e. `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` or `/baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same`) does not exist, like exemplified below

```
import os

# define the two baseDirs
dirs = 'baseDirA baseDirB'.split()

for basedir in dirs:
    try:
        cwd = f"{basedir}/the/rest/is/the/same"
        os.chdir(cwd)
        # Then I am doing the operations to parse different files
        # Below is the except statement, in case one of the directories does not exist
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"WARNING: directory {cwd} does not exist")
```

I now have three possible outcomes

1. `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` exists:

   1. I then `cd` to this directory and perform the operations I want
2. `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` does not exist but `/baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same` exists:

   1. I `cd` to `/baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same` and perform the operations I want
3. Neither `/baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same` nor `/baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same` exist.

   1. In this case, with my current `try except` statement I would get a message like so:

```
WARNING: directory /baseDirA/the/rest/is/the/same does not exist
WARNING: directory /baseDirB/the/rest/is/the/same does not exist
```

and, in this case i.e. if I fulfill the `except` statement **two times in a row** (without the operations within the `try` statement), I would like to perform something else.

What would be the best way to go about doing that? Would it be perhaps best to add another `for` loop before the one I exemplified just to check for the existence of both directories? Or can I do something below the `except` statement?

Comment: count your errors and do something when count = 2

Comment: Does the counter only increment when I have errors in a row?

Comment: If you put it to the except block, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `break` out of the for loop if the directory exists, and add an `else` clause with code that will execute if the loop is not broken out of:

```
import os

# define the two baseDirs
dirs = 'baseDirA baseDirB'.split()

for basedir in dirs:
    try:
        cwd = f"{basedir}/the/rest/is/the/same"
        os.chdir(cwd)
        ...
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"WARNING: directory {cwd} does not exist")
else:
    print("No directories existed")
```

Comment: It does the job, I am now just wondering with the print statement `No directories existed` appeared at the bottom of my file.